# Swift bitwise shift operations giving compile-time error

Tags: swift

It seems that bitwise operators don't work with UInt64 variables in Swift.

```
class Polyomino {
    var squares : UInt64 = 0
    var xLength : UInt8 = 0
    var yLength : UInt8 = 0

    func addSquareAt(x : UInt8, y : UInt8) {
        squares |= (UInt64(1) << (x + y * 8))
    }
}
```

The line with the bitwise operator gives the error "could not fin overload for "\=" with the supplied arguments". The same thing goes with the following statement:

```
squares = squares | (UInt64(1) << (x + y * 8))
```

I'm assuming this is an error on Apple's part (could be wrong) but is there any way to fix this temporarily or should I just wait for Apple for a fix? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: try cast everything to `UInt64`

Comment: Wow type safety is really much more enforced in swift huh. I needed to type cast the second part in the bit shift to UInt64 as we'll.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me editing the title of your question to make it more general. (In my case I was working with a UInt32, and maybe because of that my searching had not found this question and answer. So I was in the process of posting my own question when this luckily showed up as a "Similar question".)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type safety in Swift means that you can't do operations between different numeric types. You're trying to shift `UInt8`s against a `UInt64`, which isn't supported. Try casting the result to `UInt64` instead:

```
func addSquareAt(x : UInt8, y : UInt8) {
    squares |= 1 << UInt64(x + y * 8)
}
```

Comment: This isn't "type safety", this is idiocy. The right-hand operand of a bitwise shift operator specifies the amount of shifting to be done, and as such its type is (or should be) completely independent of the type of the left-hand operand. (Been pulling my hair out over this, and was in the process of posting a question about it when I noticed this question and answer under "Similar questions".)